# Unable to write on /dev/* files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a basic char device driver for Linux kernel.
For this, the code flow I have considered is as follows:

1. `alloc_chrdev_region()` -> to use dynamic allocation of major number
2. `class_create()`        -> to create device class in sysfs
3. `device_creat()`       -> to create device under /dev/
4. `cdv_init()`            -> to initialize char device structure
5. `cdev_add()`            -> to add my device structure in kernel

I have added read, write, open, release methods in code.

When I try to read device file under /dev/ my read method is called.
But when I try to write on /dev/ file using echo it gives error

> "bash: /dev/scull: Permission denied"

I have checked permissions of file using `ls -l`, and I have permissions to read or write on this file.

This problem occurs for every device driver module I have written. It works well in on another machine.

I'm working on ubuntu 15.10, custom compiled kernel 4.3.0

1. the result of `ls -l /dev/scull`:

   ```
   crw------- 1 root root 247, 0 Dec 30 18:06 /dev/scull
   ```
2. the exact command I used to open the file

   ```
   $ sudo echo 54 > /dev/scull
   ```
3. the source code for the open implementation

   ```
   ssize_t scull_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos){
        pr_alert("Device Written\n");
        return 0;
   }
   ```

Behavior I'm seeking here is, I should be able to see `'Device Written'` in `dmesg` ouput?

Comment: Permission denied means you don't have permission to do the action. If you sudo it, it will get past that message. Most likely you need to update your udev rules to run it without sudo.

Comment: Thanks @Dom . but I already used sudo before echo command. And it still shows same error

Comment: they are special file and nobody can touch them,

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following information:
1. the result of `ls -l /dev/null_driver`
2. the exact command you used to open the file.
3. the source code for your file operations in the kernel driver, especially the open implementation

Comment: As you can see from my question file permission is crw-------. I have changed this permission to crw----rwx and its working fine now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that you are normally not root on your bash shell. Then this command line

```
sudo echo 54 > /dev/scull
```

does not what you think. The command is executed in two steps:

1. The bash setups the output redirection, i.e., it tries to open `/dev/scull` with the current user privileges.
2. The command `sudo echo 54` is executed whereas `stdout` is connected to the file.

As you have no write-permissions as non-root user, the first step fails and  the bash reports

> "bash: /dev/scull: Permission denied"

You must already be `root` to setup the output redirection. Thus execute

```
sudo -i
```

which gives you an interactive shell with root privileges. The you can execute

```
echo 54 > /dev/scull
```

within that root shell.

Comment: Thanks @Martin that solved my problem. Can you tell me how to come back to non-root prompt?

Comment: Got it its `sudo -i -u <username>`.

Comment: @hiabcwelcome No, this command opens another sub-shell. Press CTRL+D or type the `exit` command instead.

Answer (score 3):

I know the thread is too old to answer but just in case if someone wants to know alternative method without switching to root user, here is the solution:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "54" > /dev/my_dev'
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to note that on your system only root (file owner) has read / write permissions. Your (normal) user account has not! So another (fast) solution would be to give all users read / write permissions.

**Probably this is not the safest solution! Only do this in your test environment!**

`sudo chmod a+rw /dev/scull`

But now you test your module with your user account (without sudo)

`echo "hello, world!" > /dev/scull`
`cat < /dev/scull`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so while going root with the command

```
sudo su
```

and then going into the `/dev` folder and enter your command (to save data into `/dev/scull`).

```
cd /dev
echo 54 > scull
```